# building a treestructure with BSON and Java

Tags: java, tree, bson

Given a list of String like:

```
A
A.1
A.1.B
A.1.B.X
A.1.B.X
A.1.B.X
A.1.B.X
A.1.C
A.1.C.Y
A.1.C.Y
A.1.C.Y
```

How could I make a tree stucture with the first part of the strings as parent keys?
A constraint I have is that it needs to be in BSON, because it has to go into MongoDB and I am not allowed to use extra custom objects and I also have some extra data to save.
The BSON documents have to look something like:

```
{id:A, parentId:null, children:[{id:A.1,parentId:A, children:[{id:A.1.B, parentId:A.1, children[...]}, ...]},...]}
```

Edit: 
Answer:
To solve this, I took the answer given bij Zavior to construct my basic elements.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = new HashMap<>()
```

After that, I took my list of maps and parsed trough them. I looked if an entry had a parentId and if so, I added it to the list of children of that parent. I used a Map to store the id's and the elements in.

```
map.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
        Map<String, Object> treeObject = entry.getValue();
        String parentId = (String)treeObject.get("parent");
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(parentId)) {
            Map<String, Object> parent = map.get(parentId);
            ((List<Map<String, Object>>)parent.get("children")).add(treeObject);
        }
    });
```

When I constructred the tree, I found the parents.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = map.values().stream().filter(entry -> StringUtils.isBlank((String) entry.get("parent"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's [BasicDBObject](https://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) has a constructor that accepts a map. I would just use a normal java `HashMap<String, Object>` to build the structure and pass that on to the constructor.

Something like this:

```
map.put("id", "A");
map.put("parent", null);
map.put("children", listOfChildren);
```

Note that in your example you have a list of children, thus you would create a list of maps and pass that as the list.

```
childMap.put("id", "A1");
childMap.put("parent", "A");
childMap.put("children", <another list of maps>);
listOfChildren.add(childMap):
```

Comment: And how would I get a tree structure with this? Or does the BasicDBObject do this for me?

Comment: @bobK Basically you just nest collections. See my latest edit

Comment: And that is where I am getting stuck, computing the children at the right level. The hashmap is a good tip though :)